# YouTube-Dl reject multiple titles

Tags: youtube-dl

Super super quick question, A or B answer.

I have YouTube-dl setup on my Linux machine, and have a huge list of URLS to download so it would take me weeks to find out the answer to this question.

To reject multiple titles which of the following do I do?
A
--reject-title "title1" "title2" "title3"
OR
B
--reject-title "title1" --reject-title "title2" --reject-title "title3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

`--reject-title x y z` rejects title x and downloads URLs y and z.

`--reject-title x --reject-title y --reject-title z` rejects title x, no, wait, y, no, wait z (in effect the same as `--reject-title z`).

You want a regular expression `--reject-title "x|y|z"`.

Comment: do I need to add spaces between them? Because some of my reject titles are two works, so how would I format this correctly? --reject-title " (Available | Spinnin' Sessions | Radio "

Comment: Only add spaces if you want to match spaces. If you want to reject `Available`, `Spinnin' Sessions` and `Radio`, the option would be `--reject-title "Available|Spinnin' Sessions|Radio"`